# Xcode Random Image Button, and email button

Tags: xcode, image, button, random, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to create an app that creates a random image button, and the code works. when my app generates an image, I'd like to create a button from which i can send an email with the screenshot attached...i know the codes for both actions, but when i put them in the controller h and m I've many errors...please help me!

```
@interface __3_ProductionsViewController : UIViewController 

<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)openMail:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)randomimagebutton;

{


    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

}


@end
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the errors you are getting you might want to rearrange your formatting a little. This is how I would declare the h and m.

```
// __3_ProductionsViewController.h

#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
@interface __3_ProductionsViewController : UIViewController 
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
-(IBAction)openMail:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)randomimagebutton:(id)sender;

@end

// __3_ProductionsViewController.m

#import "__3_ProductionsViewController.h"
@implementation UpdateViewController
@synthesize imageView;

-(IBAction)openMail:(id)sender {

}
-(IBAction)randomimagebutton:(id)sender {

}
@end
```

You'll need to connect the `IBActions` using interface builder as well as drag a connection to your `imageView`